# Vue.js grid module with custom filter

Tags: filter, grid, components, vue.js

What would be approximation for how you'd write component that would accept an object and organize a grid for entries that has strings that match filters for row and columns while having 2nd property in cell?

```
EG: pizza good, pizza bad, pizza raw, egg bad
columns: good, bad, raw
row: pizza
cell: pizza id or something
```